# Could Internal Ionisation Engine be a description of electric cars?

Tags: automotive-engineering, energy

Petrol powered cars are sometimes described as having an "Internal Combustion Engine" (ICE). This describes the chemical processes happening inside the engine: mainly the combustion of petrol.

Could electric cars be described with the word "Internal Ionisation Engine" (IIE). This would describe the chemical processes happening inside the batteries: oxidation/reduction and movements of ions.

Answer (score 4):

It's a very poor analogy, especially in presence of [ion engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) used for space travel, where the propellant is ionized inside the engine, then accelerated outwards.

Besides, the electric cars are based on standard electric motors - all the ion transmission happens in batteries, which are not a part of the engine. The engine is based upon rotating (or switching) induced magnetic field. Nothing "ion" to it.

Comment: In an Internal Combustion Engine, chemical reaction and transformation of energy into a mechanical force happen in one place, inside the engine. In contrast, as you wrote: "all the ion transmission happens in batteries, which are not a part of the engine". That is to say, the chemical reaction happens in the battery and the conversion of electricity into a mechanical force happens in the electric motor. Those are 2 different places. I imagine electric cars could be described as having an "External Ion Flow Engine" or an "Electric Motor Powered by Ions Flowing in an Attached Battery" EMPIFAB.

Comment: @PaulRougieux: You're overthinking it. Electric motor, chemical battery. This is engineering.SE, not philosophy.SE.

Comment: EMCB sounds good as well. I asked here because I thought engineers are probably better equipped than philosophers when it comes to naming battery and motor related stuff.

Comment: "ICE" has also been expanded as "Infernal Combustion Engine"  which does have its relevancies...

Comment: Technically,  it's an electric *motor* because the energy is produced externally, and a combustion *engine* because the energy is produced internally.  @PaulRougieux is following this convention

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "energy production" is ambiguous, to me petrol can also be seen as an energy carrier, produced externally. What would be the proper definition/terminology to use for "energy produced externally" in both cases electric motor vs. combustion engine?

Comment: @PaulRougieux: Again, not Philosophy.SE. The distinction of what is considered energy source and what is energy carrier is mostly arbitrary and traditional; usually reversible processes (where the reversal is actively pursued, not just theoretically possible) are referred to as carrying energy, while irreversible, or unpractical to reverse are energy sources - although this is not universal; if you consider a closed system where a reversible storage is not recharged, it's a source. The same electric car battery can be source in car alone, or carrier in transport system with charging stations.